# nodejs : arraystring is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am writing a program to demonstrate - User Input Validation with JOI Validating Nested Object and Arrays.

I am getting the following error: `arraystring is not defined`. How may I rectify this error?

> **app.js**

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const arrayString = ['banana','bacon','cheese'];

const arrayObjects = [{example: 'example1'}, {example: 'example2'}, {example: 'example3'}];

const userInput = {personalInfo: {

    streetAddress : '123987987',
    city : 'cuba',
    state : 'havana'
},

preferences : arraystring };

const personalInfo = Joi.object().keys({

streetAddress : Joi.string().trim().required(),
city : Joi.string().trim().required(),
state : Joi.string().trim().length(2).required()

});

const preferencesSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({

    example: Joi.string().required()

}));

const schema = Joi.object().keys({

    personalInfo : personalInfoSchema,
    preferences : preferencesSchema

});

Joi.validate(userInput,schema,(err,result)=> {

    if(err)
        console.log(err)
    else

        console.log(result);

});
```

> **Error:**

```
F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:14
preferences : arraystring };
              ^

ReferenceError: arraystring is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:14:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
PS F:\DatabaseProject9> node app.js
F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:14
preferences : arraystring };
              ^

ReferenceError: arraystring is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:14:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Probably is a case sensitive issue. You have arraystring and const arrayString

Comment: try to change "preferences : arraystring };" with preferences : arrayString }; It seems that you forget to write "s" as capital letter.

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge   Sir, do you find any error in the statement " personalInfo : personalInfoSchema". On rectifying the error you mentioned, the above error crops up.

Comment: @MutluKaya Sir, do you find any error in the statement " personalInfo : personalInfoSchema". On rectifying the error you mentioned, the above error crops up.

Comment: F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:32
    personalInfo : personalInfoSchema,
                   ^

ReferenceError: personalInfoSchema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:32:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)

Comment: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
PS F:\DatabaseProject9> node app.js
F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:32
    personalInfo : personalInfoSchema,

Comment: ReferenceError: personalInfoSchema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\DatabaseProject9\app.js:32:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)

Comment: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Comment: it may be because of case sensitive, you declared const  "arrayString" and called "arraystring"

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `preferences : arraystring` to `preferences : arrayString` because you declared `arrayString`, not `arraystring`

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const arrayString = ['banana', 'bacon', 'cheese'];

const arrayObjects = [{example: 'example1'}, {example: 'example2'}, {example: 'example3'}];

const userInput = {
    personalInfo: {
        streetAddress: '123987987',
        city: 'cuba',
        state: 'havana'
    },
    preferences: arrayObjects
};

const personalInfoSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    streetAddress: Joi.string().trim().required(),
    city: Joi.string().trim().required(),
    state: Joi.string().trim().required()
});

const preferencesSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    example: Joi.string().required()
}));

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    personalInfo: personalInfoSchema,
    preferences: preferencesSchema

});

Joi.validate(userInput, schema, (err, result) => {

    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else

        console.log(result);

});
```

Comment: Sir, do you find any error in the statement " personalInfo : personalInfoSchema". On rectifying the error you mentioned, the above error crops up

Comment: I have updated your code in my answer, this code is now working. please have a look.